# Escaping a %s within a sprintf to construct a variable field width for sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I would want to know how is it possible to escape "%*s" in a sprintf call.
 For example I have the following piece of code:

```
sprintf(log_buffer,"1234 567 89");

strcpy(format,"%*s"); 

sprintf(format1, " %%%ds %%%ds ",5,5); 

printf("\n Format is : %s ",format); 

printf("\n Format1 is : %s ",format1); 

strcat(format,format1); 

printf("\n new format is : %s ",format); 

sscanf(log_buffer,format,name,name1);

printf(" Name is 1: %s \n",name);

printf(" Name is 2: %s ",name1);
```

This works fine.

It gives me:

```
Format is : %*s 

Format1 is : %5s %5s

new format is : %*s %5s %5s

Name is 1: 567 

Name is 2: 89
```

Can I possibly not use strcpy and ignore the %*s within the sprintf itself? I tried escaping it inside sprintf but I guess it's not proper as I get a Segmentation fault.

```
sprintf(format1, " \%*s %%%ds %%%ds ",5,5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already know how to escape `%` signs in `sprintf` (by prefixing with another `%`) - you're doing it correctly for `%%%ds`.

What you want is:

```
sprintf(format1, " %%*s %%%ds %%%ds ",5,5);
```

**Edit:** The reason it's segfaulting is because `\%*s` is interpreted as a literal backslash, followed by a NULL-terminated string; so `sprintf` is trying to interpret 5 as a NULL-terminated string, which it patently isn't. It'll be running off into forbidden memory looking for a NULL-byte, and segfaulting.

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember you can mark this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark just below the voting buttons.